# Example 11 Page 83 Wayne Patty's Topology

Tags: general-topology

This question is from section Product Topology by Wayne Patty.

Example 11: For each i $\in \mathbb{N}$, let $Y_i =\mathbb{R}$. Recall that $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ denotes the cartesian product $\prod_{i\in \mathbb{N}}Y_i$. Let T denote the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$, and let U denote the box topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$. Define a function f: $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ as follows : For each x$\in \mathbb{R}$ and each n$\in \mathbb{N}$, let f(x) be the sequence whose value at n in x. Then for each i $\in \mathbb{N}$, $\pi_{i} \circ f$ is continuous but f is not continuous.

Solution: Let i$\in \mathbb{N}$. Then $\pi_i \circ f$ is the identity and it is continuous.

In order to show that f is not continuous, we exibit a member B of U such that $f^{-1}(B) $ doesn't belong to T. For each i $\in \mathbb{N}$, let $B_{i}=(-1/i , 1/i) $ and let B=$\prod_{i\in \mathbb{N}} B_i$. Let $B\in U$. The proof that $f^{-1}(B) $ doesn't belongs to T is by contradiction. Suppose $f^{-1}(B) \in T$. Then since $0\in f^{-1} (B)$, there is an open interval (a,b) such that 0$\in (a,b)$ and (a,b)$\subseteq f^{-1} (B)$. So, f((a,b))$\subseteq B$ and thus for each natural number n , $(\pi_n \circ f) ((a,b))=(a,b) \subseteq (-1/n ,1/n)$ . This is a contradiction.

How does in the line 4 of solution author deduced that $0\in f^{-1} (B)$

and how does $(\pi_n \circ f)((a,b)) \subseteq (-1/n, 1/n)$ is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ad #1:**

$$0\in f^{-1}(B)\Leftrightarrow f(0)\in B$$  What are $f(0)$?  What is $B$?

**Ad #2:**

This is miswritten.  It's not that $(\pi_n\circ f)((a,b))\subseteq\left(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)$ is a contradiction — it's that $$(a,b)\subseteq\left(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ for *all* $n$ is a contradiction.  Take $n$ large: do you see why?

Comment: I don't see why in case of Question 2 taking large n is a contradiction?

Comment: @No-One: Try it with an example.  $\left(\frac{3}{16},\frac{7}{8}\right)$ is not contained in $\left(-\frac{1}{100000},\frac{1}{100000}\right)$.  Nor is $\left(-\frac{3}{16},\frac{3}{16}\right)$.  Can you generalize that argument to other values of $a$ and $b$?